# Did Frank Herbert ever record any Dune audio books himself?

Tags: dune, audio-book

The question pretty much says it all. On Wikipedia it states

> In 1993, Recorded Books Inc. released a 20-disc audio book narrated by George Guidall. In 2007, Audio Renaissance released an audio book narrated by Simon Vance with some parts acted out by Scott Brick, Orlagh Cassidy, Euan Morton and other performers.

Is anything missing from this list. This is from the Dune page, did he record any of the later Dune books in audio format himself?

Comment: Links would help a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Frank Herbert never actually recorded *Dune* itself. He did, however, record the following:

- *Dune: A Recorded Interview* (Waldentapes, 1983), in which Herbert talks about the making of the Dune movie with the director (David Lynch), and Herbert also talks about himself
- *The Dune Audio Collection (Abridged)* (Harper Audio, 1995), which is basically compilation of a bunch of excerpts from the Dune series
- *Battles of Dune* (Harper Audio, 1994), which involves characters from the Dune series attacking each other on Dune
- *Sandworms of Dune*
- *God Emperor of Dune* (Harper Audio)
- *Heretics of Dune* (Harper Audio)

A pretty comprehensive list of the official Dune-universe audiobooks can be found at the [Collectors of Dune](http://www.collectorsofdune.com/audiobooks.asp) website.

Answer (score 7):

"*Sandworms of Dune read by the author Frank Herbert*" from Caedmon (disc TC 1565) is a 1978 33-1/3 rpm vinyl LP record of Herbert reading selections from DUNE, DUNE MESSIAH, and CHILDREN OF DUNE.  Side A is 22 minutes 14 seconds; Side B is 18 minutes 56 seconds.  Liner notes are by Herbert himself and are dated November 11, 1977.

For many of us, hearing this recording -- which predates the David Lynch movie and the SciFi Channel miniseries -- was the first time we had any idea how to pronounced so many of the made-up terms from the novels.

Comment: Robert - welcome to the site and great answer! You should edit your profile and change your user name and your description to explain who you are, since signatures in answers are typically edited out as "not being part of the answer".

Answer (score 2):

The audio recordings aren't online, AFAIK, but back in 2011, I photographed & transcribed the essays Frank Herbert wrote for 3 of them:

1. [*Sandworms of Dune*](http://www.jacurutu.com/viewtopic.php?p=101694#p101694)
2. [*Dune: The Banquet Scene*](http://www.jacurutu.com/viewtopic.php?p=101692#p101692) (Touponce, incidentally, spent a good chunk of his *Frank Herbert* book analyzing the Banquet Scene, in part based on this)

Hope they are of interest.

Comment: And also 3: [_The Battles of Dune_](http://www.jacurutu.com/viewtopic.php?p=101693#p101693)